# List of connected users

Tags: user-account, server.app

Sometimes, when need restart my Lion server, it warns me about the "connected users".

How is possible to show who is connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following terminal command to see the IP addresses of connected users:

```
netstat -f inet -n | grep '.548 ' | awk '{ print $5 }'   | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

Comment: grep followed by awk can always be combined into one awk command: `| awk '/\.548 / { print $5 }'`

Comment: ;-) thanx. So, the only way is grepping netstat for appletalk ports? Ok, while this is an working solution (i can grep for samba ports too, or simply check all connected ports) - i was hoping in something more userfriendly solution.. ;) Simply don't understadn why mac **warn** about the connected users without showing them (like: user: xxx, proto: samba or something like.. ) :) thanx anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `serveradmin` command-line utility, you can send a command to the smb or afp file sharing daemons.  Running the following will return an array of users, including their ipAddress, login time, and account name.

```
serveradmin command smb:command = getConnectedUsers
serveradmin command afp:command = getConnectedUsers
```

A typical line of output (for the user name) would appear as

```
smb:usersArray:_array_index:0:name = "user_foo"
...
smb:usersArray:_array_index:1:name = "user_bar"
```

If all you are concerned about is the user names,

```
serveradmin command smb:command = getConnectedUsers | awk -F '"' '/:name/ { print $2 }'
```

awk `-F` splits lines on the `"` , while  `/:name/` only operates on lines matching `:name`.  The `$2` takes the second column of text (divided by `"`), which is the user name.

```
user_foo
user_bar
```